# Run blender from command line with custom startup .blend file

Tags: blender

I know I can change the default startup file with `File/Defaults/Save Startup File`. I don't want to change the default startup file, but rather call blender from the command line with a custom `.blend` startup file, something like:

```
blender --startup-file my_file.blend
```

I don't want to do `blender my_file.blend` because then I can accidentally save the file and overwrite `my_file.blend`, which is supposed to be a template and not an editable file. I want to get the prompt to select the filename if I attempt to save. How can I accomplish that from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.read_homefile

```cmd
blender --python-expr "import bpy; bpy.ops.wm.read_homefile(filepath=r'my_file.blend')"
```

Or as a script:

```py
import bpy
import subprocess

path = r"D:\Desktop\test.blend"

script = "\n".join([
        "import bpy",
        f"bpy.ops.wm.read_homefile(filepath=r\"{path}\")"
    ])
    
subprocess.Popen([bpy.app.binary_path, "--python-expr", script])
```

Answer (score -1):

run

```
blender "my_file.blend" --python "my_script.py"
```

and put this in my_script.py

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath="my_new_file.blend", compress=False)
```

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#python-options
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile

Comment: My goal was to avoid pre-specifying a filename like "my_new_file.blend" but rather defer it to the user pressing ctrl + s if they decide to save the file.